# I need help fixing __str__ method. Does not return anything

Tags: python, class

I'm not too sure how the **str** method works. I want it to return the following string. "The computer has a cpu running at (var)" on the first line and on the second line it needs to follow with... "It has (var) GB RAM and has (var) GB of storage available.
Here's an example output:

**The computer has a cpu running at 3.1 Ghz**

**It has 16.0 GB RAM and has 2000.0 of storage available**

Here's the following code that I'm having trouble returning.

```
def __str__(self):
        computer_str = Computer.__str__(self), print("The computer has a cpu running at " + cpu + "Ghz")
        computer_str += Computer.__str__(self), print("It has " + ram + "GB RAM and has " + drive + " GB of storage available")
        return computer_str
```

Here is the entire code if it helps.

```
class Computer:
    def __init__(self, cpu, ram, drive):
        self.__cpu = 0
        self.__ram = 0
        self.__drive = 0

    def set_cpu(self, speed):
        self.__cpu = speed

    def get_cpu(self):
        return self.__cpu

    def set_ram(self, size):
        self.__ram = size

    def get_ram(self):
        return self.__ram

    def set_drive(self, size):
        self.__drive = size

    def get_drive(self):
        return self.__drive

    def __str__(self):
        computer_str = Computer.__str__(self), print("The computer has a cpu running at " + cpu + "Ghz")
        computer_str += Computer.__str__(self), print("It has " + ram + "GB RAM and has " + drive + " GB of storage available")
        return computer_str


print("Describe your computer")
print()
cpu = input("How fast is your computer in GHz?: ")
ram = input("How much RAM does your computer have in GB? : ")
drive = input("How much drive space does your computer have in GB?: ")
computer1 = Computer(cpu, ram, drive)
```

Comment: What is being returned erroneously?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be printing within the `__str__` function. Also, not sure why you are recursively calling `__str__` within your `__str__` function, that will turn into an endless loop.

What you want is something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    computer_str = "The computer has a cpu running at " + cpu + "Ghz \n"
    computer_str += "It has " + ram + "GB RAM and has " + drive + " GB of storage available"
    return computer_str
```

When you call `print` on `computer1` , it will print the above string. The `\n` will cause it to appear on two lines.

Now, the above code will not work because you are not accessing the `cpu`, `drive`, and `ram` variables correctly, but that is a separate issue

You are also not setting these variables when you instantiate the object, but that is also another issue

Comment: Should be `__self.cpu`, `__self.ram`, and `__self.drive`. Edit: added leading `__` @chepner

Comment: Well, `self.__cpu` et al., given the current state of the class. It *should* be `self.cpu`, assuming all the boilerplate isn't a pointless requirement of the assignment.

Comment: Yes, and they would actually need to set these variables in the `__init__`, instead of setting them to 0. Or call the setter methods